# Unexpected String Conversion Issue in Android Shared Preferences when Storing

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences, token

I am encountering an unusual issue while attempting to store a date in SharedPreferences. The server sends the date in the format: "date": "2024-01-14T21:45:05Z". However, when I try to save this value in SharedPreferences, it seems to automatically convert into a random string.

```
 "date" : "2024-01-14T21:45:05Z" // response
<string name="date">cUqOhoRqTDmDUjx0Q3oOtK:APA91bGt4IYRb6Yw4lAX9kOEfIPYy2BCRRl-naR5Q0J797W3FvrLLDUYPMIknI1azCnTq8B5-KLdWLQZbBz56DS_ptHQZ2SgK15Lts7ar1N2fwdEAv0xdoLafAP-9qI5YVQJCExfSqH9</string> // value in SharedPreference
```

Comment: Please add the relevant code.

Comment: are you storing the string value of the date?

Comment: encrypted shared preferences